# Sandbox, does FeatureReceiver work in Office365?

Tags: sandbox-solution, feature-activation

Sandbox with code are disabled in SharePoint Online. Does it mean that I cannot use Feature Receivers?

I have a sandbox solution with reciever, it works ok but if I check "Include assembly in package" to false

[image]

I get deployment error:

> Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': Unable to load
>   assembly group. The user assembly group provider was unable to provide
>   any user assemblies for the specified assembly group.

Does it mean that if I want to use "Office365-friendly" solution - I can't use feature receivers?

**upd.:** Created Module and wanted to clear my files in FeatureDeactivating event in Feature receiver. Thanks for Your answers, understand that it is impossible.

However, I found how to force overwrite my files in module without clearing with code:

```
<File Path="SomeFolder\jquery-3.1.1.min.js" Url="SomeFolder/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" Type="GhostableInLibrary" ReplaceContent="TRUE"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately yes, you can't use feature receivers.
To recap here is what is no longer available for Online:

- Event
- Feature receivers
- Workflows (coded)
- InfoPath forms (if using code behind the forms)
- Web parts (if coded using sandbox code)

The only option is to use remote event receivers and new add-in model.
Check out also this excelent writing around custom code deprecation for sandbox - [Sandbox code no longer available in Office 365](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2016/08/sandbox-code-disabled-in-Office-365.html)

More info about remote event receivers - [Create a remote event receiver in SharePoint Add-ins](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220043.aspx) and [Handle events in SharePoint Add-ins](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220048.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

it is gone from Office 365 and you have to use new app model/add-in to create your stuff.

this is official statement.

> While developing sandboxed solutions that contain only declarative
>   markup and JavaScript — which we call no-code sandboxed solutions
>   (NCSS) — is still viable, we have deprecated the use of custom managed
>   code within the sandboxed solution.

[Deprecation of Custom Code in Sandboxed Solutions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sharepointdev/2014/01/14/deprecation-of-custom-code-in-sandboxed-solutions/)

Comment: Thank You! I wanted to clear folder with my scripts in FeatureDeactivating event, now I understand it is impossible..